# How to fetch URL from a String in groovy

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have one file in which I stored a output of git push command. It's output looks like this,

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 315.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/...
   99d7..344  <branch> -> <branch>
Branch newBranch set up to track remote branch newBranch from origin.
```

I stored this output in one variable and now I want to do manipulation on that variable and fetch only URL like,

```
https://githhub.com/...
```

It's a Jenkins pipeline code.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways by using some API provided by Jenkins or Github, but if that's unavailable, I would suggest a regex if you know the pattern will remain consistent

```
    String foo = "";
    String bar = "Counting objects: 3, done.\nDelta compression using up to 8 threads.\nCompressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.\nWriting objects: 100% (3/3), 315 bytes | 315.00 KiB/s, done.\nTotal 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)\nTo https://github.com/...\n   99d7..344  <branch> -> <branch>\nBranch newBranch set up to track remote branch newBranch from origin.";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^to\\s+(.*$)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(bar);
    if(m.find()) {
        foo = m.group(1);
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
    System.out.println(foo);
    Output: https://github.com/...
```